# Calculate formula in Mysql Procedure

Tags: mysql, regex, database, stored-procedures, formula

I have a column in table which has all the formulas E.g: #23+#34+#78+#56 and each number will refer to some other table and I have to fetch corresponding values for each Number and calculate based on the formula.

Eg. a row contains formula as #45+#34/#56*#23-#78 , then I have to get corresponding value of ID 45 and get all values of each ids and calculate the expression.

How should I go about doing this. Any suggestions Please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "formulas" and "calculate the expression"?

Comment: You need to write an expression parser. SQL isn't the best language for that kind of thing. Do you have to do it in the database?

Comment: @Connum : I meant, to calculate the formula.

Comment: @acfrancis: Yes I have to do that in database. Any suggestions ?

Comment: You could try looping through the string, replacing every occurence of ``#nn`` with the result of ``select column from table where id=nn`` and then evaluating the resulting string as a dynamic SQL statement. Sounds like a pain to write and it doesn't cover the case where one of the referenced ids also contains an expression.